# Proto buffer backward compatibility issue when field name is changed from capital to small

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

In current version of protobuff my oneoff looks something like below :

```
oneof oneof_abc {
 double Value = 1;
}
```

But in updated version it looks like :

```
oneof oneof_abc {
 double value = 1;
}
```

If you notice v in value is changed to small case.

I want to write in way it should support both the versions.

Is it possible?

I am using proto3.

I went through the documents but did not get any clue.

Comment: It's not entirely backward compatible. On-the-wire (binary) messages reference the field by its field number (`1`) not name (`Value`|`value`), so a binary (!) message sent using stubs generated from the old proto will be compatible with the new proto and vice versa. However (!) you will need to retain stubs for the old version so that you don't break old code **and** non-binary representations (e.g. JSON) **may** break if the JSON field name changes as a result (I'm unsure whether it will in this case).

Comment: Funnily enough, making a breaking change (such as changing the case, or just completely changing the name altogether) is a really good way to evaluate the impact of a bigger planned change. For example, say you had a field named "bearing" and that it was agreed that this was in degrees. Say you then wanted it to be radians instead. Changing the name to "bearing_rads" and breaking the build shows you just how many places in your source code you're going to have to adapt to the change from degrees to radians. It's also a good way of making sure that every required change has been made.

Answer (score 0):

I used Golang but...

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Bar {
  oneof oneof_abc {
    double value = 1;
  }
}
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    pb "github.com/.../76273079/protos"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)

// upper is a function that writes binary|JSON messages using Value
func upper() {
    bar := &pb.Bar{
        OneofAbc: &pb.Bar_Value{
            Value: 3.14159265358979,
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", bar)

    // to binary
    b, _ := proto.Marshal(bar)
    os.WriteFile("foo.bin", b, 0644)

    // to JSON
    j, _ := protojson.Marshal(bar)

    fmt.Printf("%+s", j)
}

// lower is a function that reads binary and write JSON using value
func lower() {
    b, _ := os.ReadFile("foo.bin")

    bar := &pb.Bar{}

    // from binary
    _ = proto.Unmarshal(b, bar)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", bar)

    // to JSON
    j, _ := protojson.Marshal(bar)

    fmt.Printf("%+s", j)
}
func main() {
    //upper()
    lower()
}
```

It's hacky but it demonstrates the point.

I swap `Value`-->`value` between `upper` and `lower` and re-`protoc`

Using `upper` (`Value`)

```
Value:3.14159265358979
{"Value":3.14159265358979}
```

JSON has `Value`

Using `lower` (`value`) which reads the binary message created by `upper`

```
value:3.14159265358979
{"value":3.14159265358979}
```

It reads the binary message without issue

JSON has `value`